# How can free electrons be contained?

Tags: electrons

Especially, what is the maximum storage density of free electrons that current technology can achieve and what technology would that be?
I am talking about free electrons, not bound to nuclei or in metals. I assume two things, but please feel free to correct me:
1. It is possible to generate a static field that will contain the electrons between walls, but will consume energy in proportion to the developed pressure
2. It is not possible to use a passive material to contain electrons beyond a certain density, but I am unsure why not. If all shells are full, what happens to the other electrons? Do they break the walls, filter out,etc?

Comment: As in a Penning trap?

Comment: Maybe, I don't know containment methods, thus my question. Feel free to expand.

Comment: Search for "Penning trap", as Pieter suggested.